# Are any HTTP log files saved on my system by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have an application hosted on Amazon EC2 on a Ubuntu machine, written in Ruby (on Rails), deployed with Capistrano and running on Nginx.

Last friday one module of my application has crashed and nobody in the company noticed until this morning. We spent some money with Facebook and Google ads and received a few hundreds of visits, but nobody created an account due to this bug.

I wonder if this configuration is saving the HTTP requests and its bodies somewhere in a log file. But we didnt explicitly set it, so it would only happen if any of these technologies do it by default.

Do you know whether there is such log or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that wouldn't be anywhere in a usable form (I'm inferring you want to try to create the accounts from request bodies in log files). You'll have the requests themselves in your nginx logs, and the rails logs will contain more info about the request, but as a matter of security, by default, any sensitive information (e.g. passwords) would be scrubbed from them. You may still be able to get some info from them.

To answer your question a little more specifically, the usual place for these logs on your system would be:

- `/var/log/nginx/`
- `/path/to/your/rails/app/log/production.log`

On a separate note, I would recommend looking into an error reporting service like Honeybadger, Airbrake, Raygun, Appsignal, or others so that you don't have silent failures like this moving forward.